# Edit mode bug, everything does not move in one piece

Tags: modeling, rigging

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=749BKifmRC4&feature=youtu.be

The problem is that when I move my mesh in edit mode, half of it on axis X moves as if it was mirrored, though the mirror modifier is **not** applied. One plane of the vertecies remains still on the same axis of origin of the model.

Comment: Hi. Please describe the problem fully in the question body itself. If that link goes down at some point this question will become very unclear. This site isn't just for the people asking the questions, but for the people in future who have the same issue as you and will search this site. If the question is unclear they wont know they're having the same problem as you and whether any answers you get could be of use to them.

Comment: [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a video](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hidden the *Tool Settings Header* which contains the mirror editing options while you're in editing mode.

Right-click on the top header and go to *Header > Show Tool Settings*. Then you can disable the mirror editing shown below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, didn't know about this feature. Quite useful :). It's also in *Sidebar > Tool > Options.*